# Changing date format in datagridview

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, date-format

I have an excel file which contain two columns of dates, the format of the date is `mm/dd/yyyy` . Now I am exporting it to my DataGridView and save it to my database. But after saving it, the format of the dates are changed, it is `mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss`. How would I save it on my database with the format of `mm/dd/yyyy` only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, try to set the datatype of those columns to Date instead of DateTime.

Comment: thanks it help me but the format is yyyy-mm-dd, can i still change it to mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: It's how the data is stored and represent in database in `yyyy-MM-dd` format and you don't need to change that. What you want is, perhap, to display that date to the user in the format of `MM/dd/yyyy`. In that case you can do that by using `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` or if you bind to a gridview databound column, use `DataFormat="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"` to display. (`mm` is minute, not month, you should use capitalized `MM` do show month).